# Ubuntu 20.04 charging starts and stops randomly

Tags: 20.04, laptop, ppa, battery, indicator

I recently started using Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm very new to this Linux distribution. I installed it on my HP laptop. Everything was great.

The problem is that when I charge the laptop while using it, charging stops and starts randomly. Whenever charging stops, the battery LED on the laptop turns white, indicating that the laptop has been fully charged. But the battery percentage on the top bar will show 65% or 70% and the battery life is stuck on estimating.

I think the battery is fine, since it works on my other laptop which has Windows 10 on it.

I came across this app called BATTERY STATUS and decided to install it. But the terminal says something like "you can't securely install from this untrusted site and the option is disabled by default".

Can someone help me please?

Comment: The charging of batteries is handled by your hardware, the OS is only an observer (so as to report to the user on charging/discharging state & to adjust screen brightness or other chosen settings).  To me you're describing a hardware issue with your battery which cannot be fixed by the OS (the passive observer).  *Check your cable is properly inserted... I noted a laptop responding weirdly the other day (charging/discharging, bright/less-bright screen) & took me awhile to recogize it was the cable incorrectly inserted*..